# new Thread making only first instruction and never resumes

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Here is my problem:

I'm creating threads

```
HANDLE Threads[THREAD_NUM]
```

Launch the thread

```
void LaunchThread (int i) {
  *some checks if the handle is not null etc*;
  DWORD threadId;
  threads[i] = CreateThread ( 
    NULL,
    0,
    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)*StaticMethodInvokingTheThreadFunc, 
    *StructPassingToThatMethod ( basically have a pointer and thread number)*,
    0,
    &threadId);
  *DebugMessage "thread created"*;
  *DebugMessage "with id = (threadId)"*;
}
```

Static method invokes function

```
void DoSmth () {
  *DebugMessage "thread func started"*;
  ...;
  *then code with another messages all the way*;
}
```

Waiting function is simple

```
void WaitThread (i){
  *DebugMessage "wait for thread to finish"*;
  WaitForSingleObject (Threads[i], INFINITE);
}
```

And in main function the sequence:

```
LaunchThread (i);
WaitThread (i);
```

Program never returns the `WaitThread ()` function, and(!) the list of messages looks like

```
"thread created"
"thread func started" (and nothing done after that message in DoSmth () func)
"with id = .."
"wait for thread to finish"
```

This happens even with 1 thread...
For a couple of threads i simply have

```
 for ( int t = 0; t < THREAD_NUM; t++)
   LaunchThread (t);
```

and the same loop for waiting threads

Why is this happening?
I tried to `ResumeThread ()`, to close handle to thread and relaunch it, but nothing helped.

Comment: Maybe `StaticMethodInvokingTheThreadFunc` has incorrect signature or calling convention. Why do you think you need to cast?

Comment: The call of *DebugMessage ...* is one code line, but more than one instruction. How did you verify that there is no "second instruction" executed? I would assume that the thread waits somewhere.

Comment: You're right, i meant one code line.

Comment: Henrik: i meant that it is just some static method. The entire method looks like static DWORD WINAPI StaticThreadStart (void* Param)

Comment: So all you do in the thread function is print messages? What is actually happening there?

Comment: no, it generates data and then make some calculations ( it should ;p)

Comment: @I.Alexandrov: Any point where it could get stuck? Can you check if the thread function terminates correctly?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that function StaticMethodInvokingTheThreadFunc does not really have a signature of LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, but this is masked by the fact that the function pointer is forcefully cast to it. Remove the cast. If compiler starts to complain then adapt the signature of your function.

It could be that calling CreateThread is wrong in your case. It is wrong in 99% cases, and you should really call CRT library function `_beginthreadex`. This function internally calls CreateThread, but it also does some initialization stuff. Replace CreateThread with _beginthreadex.

It could be that the execution is hang in StaticMethodInvokingTheThreadFunc, after the text "thread func started" is printed. Revise the code in the function, or place a breakpoint on last function's line and debug the project to see if breakpoint will be hit.

Comment: Problem is - i'm not using VS and i can't use crt. And compiler doesnt understand __declspec etc. so it cant include VC/include/process.h. How can i include it then?

Comment: So, what do you use? There should be some function equivalent to _beginthreadex in the library and with the compiler that you use. But let's focus on my third paragraph. Have you tried to just debug the thread step by step? There must be a step by step debugging functionality in your development environment.

Comment: I'm using borland, the old one ;p I'll search for _beginthread analog, but i'm not really sure it exists there... I removed all debug messages and traced the function - at CreateThread static method is called, it then calls DoSmth (), that goes to the end and static method finishes correctly too.

Comment: So i have a question about how i can control the time, when DoSmth is called ( if i want to do it not right on the creation). Should i use Events for this?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Feel free to ask more questions, but it is better if you ask them as standalone separate questions.